# margin-left style not working on second <td> element

Tags: html, css, html-table

A table with two cells side by side:

```
<table>
  <td disabled>Something Here</td>
  <td style="margin-left:100px;" disabled>Second Cell</td>    
</table>
```

The `margin-left:100px` does nothing to separate the second cell from the first cell.  How do I create space to the left of the second cell?

### Padding Left

`padding-left:100px`

**Produces this result:**

[image]

The *content* of the second cell now has 100px of space added to the left.  The position of the cell *background* however remains unchanged.

### Border-spacing

`<table style="border-spacing: 100px 0; margin: 0 -100px">`

Produces this result:

### [image]

If I add a third table cell, I get this result:

[image: Three Cells]

I don't want spacing between *every* cell, just the second one.

### Cellspacing

`cellspacing` in the table element creates spacing around every cell.  I don't want that either, and one source states that `cellspacing` is not supported in HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `<td>` element, set text color to same as background, and background-color to transparent, enter number of characters you want for spacing.

### Illustration with background shown for display purposes:

```
<table>
  <td>Something Here</td>
  <td style='color:white; background-color: green'>123456</td>
  <td>Second Cell</td>
  <td>Third Cell</td>
</table>
```

[image: Cell Spacing]

Creates a 'Dummy Cell' with a spacing of 6 characters.  Now set background to transparent.

### Cell Background Set to Transparent and Text Color set to same as Parent Element.

```
<table>
  <td>Something Here</td>
  <td style='color:white; background-color: transparent;'>123456</td>
  <td>Second Cell</td>
  <td>Third Cell</td>
</table>
```

[image]

So far, my preferred method would be to simply add another `<td>` element for spacing.  But I'm open to any better solution.

Answer (score 2):

`Margin` wont work with table cells. Try `padding` or `cellspacing=""` to table.

Or add a `div` inside the table cell and apply margin to the div.

```
<td style="padding-left:100px;" disabled>Second Cell</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to CSS specifications, [`margin` properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin-left) do not apply to table cells (elements with `display: table-cell`). It is valid to set them, but the setting has no effect.

The way to separate the cells of a table is to set [`border-spacing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-border-spacing) on the `table` element, e.g. with `<table style="border-spacing: 100px 0">`. However, this also sets the spacing between the cells and the edges of the table. This effect can be cleared using negative margins:

```
<table style="border-spacing: 100px 0; margin: 0 -100px">
  <td disabled>Something Here</td>
  <td disabled>Second Cell</td>    
</table>
```

Caveat: IE 7 (and older) does not support `border-spacing`, but it supports `margin` properties, so on it the result would be all wrong. If this is relevant, put the CSS code in a `style` element and wrap it inside a “pseudocomment” that makes IE 7 and older ignore it.

Depending on the context, the simpler method of just setting left margin on the second cell may work well. However, it creates spacing *inside the second cell*, not between the cells. The difference between this and cell spacing matters e.g. if cells have backgrounds or borders.